# How to connect to mongodb with IAM from ECS fargate?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I'm having an ECS service, running on fargate. I want to use my task role to connect with mongodb. I've already enabled that role ARN on mongodb side. My issue now is that I cannot get a session token with `sts.getSessionToken`, because I'm getting `AccessDenied: Cannot call GetSessionToken with session credentials`.

Doing a further research, my ECS container is assuming the task role, and based on my readings an assumed role cannot assume another role, or generate credentials.

How do I connect to mongodb then with my assumed IAM role? Is there a way to get the current assumed role's credentials inside the container?

Comment: what driver do you use? Mongo drivers support aws authentication including on ECS instances, so you don't need specifying anything special

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon ECS agent populates the `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` environment variable in the Env object for all containers.

From inside the container, you can query the credential endpoint with the following command:

`curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`

Output:

```
{
    "AccessKeyId": "ACCESS_KEY_ID",
    "Expiration": "EXPIRATION_DATE",
    "RoleArn": "TASK_ROLE_ARN",
    "SecretAccessKey": "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
    "Token": "SECURITY_TOKEN_STRING"
}
```

Using these temp credentials via your driver, you should be able to connect to your MongoDB cluster provided the Mongo side configuration is done correctly.

We've used these for some other authentication purpose rather than mongo, but I don't see why it should not work for you.

Some AWS ECS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Based on https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/authentication/mechanisms/#mongodb-aws this guide, it should automatically fetch the credentials from `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`, and I've checked, it exists, and has value inside the container, but I'm getting `user is not allowed to do action find on database.collection`

Comment: Tried manually fetching the endpoint as you suggested, and it gives response in the format you provided, but I'm getting `MongoServerError: bad auth : aws sts call has response 403` have you met with this issue?

Comment: As mentioned, we didn't use it with MongoDb or DB's specifically. 
I can still try to help though: Could you share the connection string you are using to connect to the MongoDb?